# Jquery data-attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's duplicate but please see below;

my anchor link

```
 <a onclick="updateStatus(this)" data-pid="@job.Id" data-act="@action.Activity" data-sts="@action.StatusToSet" class="btn btn-xs btn-circle @action.CssClass @action.BackgroundColor" href="#">
                                            @action.Text
                                        </a>
```

my javascript function

```
function updateStatus(elem) {
    var preAssignedJobId = $(elem).attr("data-pid");
    var activity = $(elem).attr("data-act");
    var statusToSet = $(elem).attr("data-sts");
}
```

but I am getting Undefined for all of the above. I can't see any problem, can someone point. My version of jquery is 1.11.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: While it is unrelated to your problem, I want to point out that `.data("pid")` potentially converts your id to an integer. This may or may not be desirable. Using `.attr("data-pid")` returns a string which you can handle more predictably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `this` as a parameter when you are calling `updateStatus()`

```
<a onclick="updateStatus(this)" data-pid="@job.Id" data-act="@action.Activity" data-sts="@action.StatusToSet" class="btn btn-xs btn-circle @action.CssClass @action.BackgroundColor" href="#">
                                            @action.Text
                                        </a>
```

And the argument to this function

```
function updateStatus(param) {
    //  Then use param
    var preAssignedJobId = $(param).data("pid");
    var activity = $(param).data("act");
    var statusToSet = $(param).data("sts");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your element to the function.

```js
function updateStatus(elm) {
    var preAssignedJobId = $(elm).data("pid");
    var activity = $(elm).data("act");
    var statusToSet = $(elm).data("sts");
    $(elm).text("hhH");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="updateStatus(this)" data-pid="@job.Id" data-act="@action.Activity" data-sts="@action.StatusToSet" class="btn btn-xs btn-circle @action.CssClass @action.BackgroundColor" href="#">
                                            @action.Text
                                        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delegate a `click` event to the `anchor` and extract the info needed.

```
$('a').on("click",function(e)
{
    //e.preventDefault();
    var preAssignedJobId = $(this).data("pid");
    alert(preAssignedJobId);
    var activity = $(this).data("act");
    var statusToSet = $(this).data("sts");

});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/opmy3n8j/

Answer (score -1):

Since you are already using jQuery, remove your onclick from the HTML code and us a jQuery event handler for that.

***HTML***

```
 <a id="anch1" data-pid="@job.Id" data-act="@action.Activity" data-sts="@action.StatusToSet" class="btn btn-xs btn-circle @action.CssClass @action.BackgroundColor" href="#">
                                            @action.Text
                                        </a>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(function(){
    $("#anch1").click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var preAssignedJobId = $this.data("pid");
      var activity = $this.data("act");
      var statusToSet = $this.data("sts");
    });
});
```